# How do you hide Django model fields with foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a seminar that has several multiple choice questions.

Here is the seminar model:

```
class Seminar(models.Model):
    seminar_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    seminar_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And here is the model for the multiple choice questions:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    seminar = models.ForeignKey(Seminar)
    multiple_choice_group = models.ForeignKey(MultipleChoiceGroup, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Multiple Choice Question")
    page_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Page ID")
```

I have the following in admin.py:

```
class PageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Page
    extra = 0
    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['page_id']

    # Limit the multiple choice questions that match the seminar that is being edited.
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "multiple_choice_group":
            try:
                parent_obj_id = request.resolver_match.args[0]
                kwargs["queryset"] = MultipleChoiceGroup.objects.filter(seminar = parent_obj_id)
            except IndexError:
                pass

        return super(PageInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

class SeminarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Seminar
    inlines = (PageInline,)
    list_display = ('seminar_name', 'is_active')
    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['seminar_name']
```

This is how the seminar appears:

[Screenshot showing seminar fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOYdg.jpg)

As shown in the screenshot, I'd like to hide some of the fields from the Seminar model and make some of them read-only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Model.Admin exclude and readonly_fields attributes. See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).

For example:

```
class SeminarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Seminar
    inlines = (PageInline,)
    list_display = ('seminar_name', 'is_active')
    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['seminar_name']

    exclude = ('seminar_name',)
    readonly_fields = ('is_active',)
```